# Public anonymous access to local TFS2013 git repository

Tags: git, tfs

Is it possible to configure local TFS2013 server to enable anonymous (unauthenticated) read-only access to git repository over http:// or git:// protocol ?

Answer (score -1):

You can add the Windowsgroup "everyone" in the security Settings and add them to the TFS group "Reader"

Comment: Very hacky but I worked around this by specifying a blank username/password at the start of the URL. I.E. http://:@localhost:8080/git/repo